# Is there any way to copy data between two clusters using Distcp , which are not reachable directly via a 3rd machine?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, distcp

We have a requirement to move complete data from an on premise hadoop cluster to another stored in cloud. I wanted to know if is there any way in which we can use DistCP / its alternatives for moving the bulk data to cloud storage via a local machine with connectivity to both?

P.S : Cloud components - HDInsight and BLOB Storage

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the third machine to kick off the distcp job in one of the 2 machines. Use ssh to and write a script which initiates the job on one of the 2 machines. Let me know if you need more explanation i can post the answer.

Comment: Have you tried yet? What error did you get?

Comment: @roh The issue here is that they are not reachable directly via each other... So starting a job via distcp in one would fail as it wouldn't be able to connect to the destination machine.

Comment: You need connection